# Finding point of contact of a sphere in an image

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have an image, in which there is a table, and on this table, a sphere. I would like to find the point of contact between the sphere and the table.

This point can be the center of the sphere, for example if the image is taken from above. This point can also be the bottom point of the sphere, for example if the image is taken with a gaze parallel to the table's plane.

**Data** : the table's outlines polygon and the circle surrounding the sphere.

Example : I have an image of this kind : http://www.dkbilliards.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/121-866x650.jpg and I want to find the point of contact between the table and the white ball.

Comment: Taking the table as having a surface parallel to the $xy$ plane, then the contact point is "below" the center of the sphere, which means that it has $xy$ coordinates from the sphere center and $z$ coordinate from the table surface...

Comment: Yes, but how can we find these coordinates given the data that we have ?